# DRF, modelSerializer related nested tables

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to serialize related tables but can't manage the include nested table's nest. Let's say. I have a `Project` model.

```
class Project(models.Model):

  project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  path = models.CharField(max_length=50)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.project_name
```

and this project model has many relationship with the `Plan` model.

```
class Plan(models.Model):

  project = models.ForeignKey(Project,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name="plans")
  ...
  ...

  def __str__(self):
    return self.type
```

everything is fine. 'till here I am serializing the project table with the nested `Plan` **BUT** `Plan` model has `hasMany` relationship too (with the `PlanImage` model)

```
class PlanImage(models.Model):
  plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name="plan_images")
  ... 
  ...
```

So in my `serializers.py` if I do:

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Project
    fields = ["id", "project_name", "path", "plans"]
    depth = 1
```

Project has coming with the nested Plan table but. in the Plan table, of course there is no PlanImage table. I checked the [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) but couldn't find the way. How can I include `PlanImage` into `Plan`?

Comment: have you tried `depth = 2` ?

Comment: yes, it only putting the Project model's fields inside the Plan table. @ArakkalAbu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [***nested serialization***](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) technique

```
class PlanImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlanImage
        fields = ['required', 'fields']


class PlanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    plan_images = PlanImageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Plan
        fields = ['id', 'plan_images']


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    plans = PlanSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ["id", "project_name", "path", "plans"]
```